# POST two data with a single form field

Tags: php, forms

I've a dozen of triplet `{year - month - day}` into an HTML select input.

For the moment I do:

```
<select name="period">
    <option value="2014-10-23">
```

And then in PHP:

```
explode('-', $_POST['period'])
```

I wonder if it is possible with PHP to directly get these value into different variable?

Something like:

```
<select name="year;month;day">
    <option value="2014;10;23">

$_POST['year']
$_POST['month']
$_POST['day']
```

Comment: Better is you create three selects for year, month, date respectively.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary why is that better? You don't know what the OP wants.

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary what is better about creating a bigger source for the same result ?

Comment: If you want to use only a single select, then `explode` is  the only way to go

Comment: @RohitKumarChoudhary This is the existing form field way, but it's not enought user friendly. Actually it's not a combo box that allow the selection of every year, every month, and then every day. It's a combo box which allow the selection of very specifics date (only a dozen).

Comment: @asprin thats not true `preg_split()` and `split` for PHP 5.3 <= are also both valid.

Comment: @Fractaliste is it possible for you to design the data like i postet it in my bottom post ?

Answer (score 1):

you could try this here (untested)

```
<select name="period">
    <option value='{"year":2014,"month":10,"day":23}'>2014-10-23</option>
```

and convert it with

```
$myDate = json_decode($_POST['period']);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($myDate);
echo "</pre>";
```

in this case you can also easily pass the data to javascript/ajax because you can translate jsonString into array too.

Comment: Interresting approach!

Answer (score 1):

Untested code here

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
    $keys = explode(';',$key);
    $values = explode(';',$value);
    if(count($keys) > 1 && count($keys) === count($values)){
       unset($_POST[$key]);
       foreach($keys as $i=>$k){
          $_POST[$k] = $values[$i];
       }
    }
}
```

Ad this to the entry point of your scripts and it should automatically convert the format you described

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple field, you have to send multiple field

```
<input name="year" /><input name="month" />...
```

which is completly acceptable. You can still style the field so they look as one field.

If you want only one field, you have to split the data in php

```
list($year, $month, $day) = explode(';', $_POST['date']);
```

Comment: than he has 3 vars for one date ?!?!? hmm... Should use `$date['year']` and so on...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach: storing the date in a [`DateTime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object. Basically, you have one variable (`$date`), that contains an object (an instance of PHP's `DateTime` class), and you can use it's methods (in this case, the `format()` method) to retrieve the year, month, day and/or other properties (such as day of the week, etc).

You can use your existing HTML:

```
<select name="period">
    <option value="2014-05-22">May 22, 2014</option>
</select>
```

In the PHP script that processes the input, create a variable `$date` that contains a DateTime object:

```
$date = new DateTime($_POST['period']);
```

By initializing a new `DateTime` object and passing it the date (in `Y-m-d` format), the `DateTime` object will automatically hold the right date value.

Now you can use the [`format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method on that object to retrieve the year, month and day:

```
echo $date->format('Y'); //2014
echo $date->format('m'); //05
echo $date->format('d'); //22
```

Note: `DateTime::format()` accepts the same [`format` parameters](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php#refsect1-function.date-parameters) as the [`date()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) does.

Also note that, even though you only passed it a date (and no time), the `$date` variable still holds a complete `DateTime` object. It's value is stored internally as `2014-05-22 00:00:00` by PHP, so `$date->format('H:i:s')` will return `00:00:00`. This shouldn't have any effect of course if you only use `Y`, `m` and `d` in your `format` parameter.

Comment: It makes sense. Do you know how to make it works if I've only the year and the month?

Comment: That's actually a new question... however, I don't think it should be a problem. `$date = new \DateTime('2014-05');` is stored internally by PHP as `2014-05-01 00:00:00` (as if you had passed `2014-05-01`), so you can still use the `format()` method without any problems, as long as you understand that `format('d')` will simply return `01`.